# How do I install ebook reader? Problems with FBReader

Tags: 13.04, ebooks

I try to install FBReader via Ununtu Software Center, but it stalls for a long time and even after the process is supposedly complete, Ubuntu doesn't display epub and mobi files when I click them. It says "There is no application installed for “Mobipocket e-book” files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?" and this process doesn't finish. What should I do?

Alternatively, I need something to display epub/mobi files.

My internet connection is ok; e.g. I am able to install system via ubuntu netinstall without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [calibre](http://packages.ubuntu.com/calibre) [image: Install calibre]

[image: Install via the software center]

**Overview**

Calibre is a free and open source e-book library management application developed by users of e-books for users of e-books.

Calibre is primarily a ebook cataloging program. It manages your ebook collection for you. It is designed around the concept of the logical book, i.e. a single entry in the database that may correspond to ebooks in several formats. It also supports conversion from a dozen different ebook formats to LRF and EPUB. A graphical interface to the conversion software can be accessed easily by just clicking the "Convert E-books" button.

Supported input formats are: MOBI, AZW, LIT, PRC, EPUB, ODT, HTML, CBR, CBZ, RTF, TXT, PDF and LRS.

---

**Starting calibre's ebook viewer as a standalone application**

In certain cases you will not want to add an EPUB or MOBI file to calibre's library before reading it. Luckily calibre's ebook viewer can be started independently via `ebook-viewer`. This makes it possible to create a standalone launcher:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=calibre
Exec=ebook-viewer %f
Name=Ebook Viewer
Comment=Display .epub files and other e-reader formats
StartupWMClass=ebook-viewer
MimeType=application/x-mobipocket-ebook;application/epub+zip;
```

See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) for more information on adding launchers to your system.

---

**To click an ebook and open in ebook-viewer**, make this application (`usr/bin/ebook-viewer`) the default for that type of file.

Comment: Will Calibre work as a simple ebook viewer, too? e.g. I want to open ebook by double-clicking it, check it out and not add to my library or download to my e-reader device.

I guess, with Ubuntu installing from repositories should generally work just fine? Just installed it; seems to work. But when I double-click an ebook, it still goes "There is no application installed for “Mobipocket e-book” files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?"

Comment: I select "Open With" but where is "Add button"? If you meant "Other Application", there's no option to point to this file, too.

Comment: if nothing work check this http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/ubuntu-fix-add-program-to-list-of-applications-in-open-with-when-right-clicking-files-in-nautilus/

Comment: No, "Other Application" puts me into this http://i298.photobucket.com/albums/mm249/hrenistic/find1app_zpsd8dd1362.png then this http://i298.photobucket.com/albums/mm249/hrenistic/find1app_zpsd8dd1362.png Will look into additional information, thanks.

Comment: come to the chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9957/default-application

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov
Edit the file /usr/share/applications/calibre.desktop .Change
Exec=calibre To be Exec=’/usr/bin/calibre’ %f

Comment: Did it. So, what should this have accomplished? And how do I write in that chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9968/discussion-between-nickolai-leschov-and-stormvirux)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. If you use Firefox browser, you can install EPUB Reader from its Add-On manager.

Comment: Do you mean I could install an add-on like this?

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/epubreader/

It works, but I would prefer a native ebook reader application in my system.